# How to merge arrays by concatenating the values?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge 2 arrays by concatenating their values. Right now I use `array_merge()`, but that doesn't give me the expected result.

Code:

```
$software1 = $_POST['software1'];
$software2 = $_POST['software2'];
$software3 = array_filter($software2);

$result = array_merge($software1, $software3);
foreach($result as $value){
    echo $value . "<br>";
}
```

Current output:

```
software
software
software
1
2
3
```

What I would like:

```
software 1
software 2
software 3
```

Comment: Just make sure you know that on a real site on the web, that you'll need to take precautions with anything from a post/get/cookie, because it's user provided. If you print it onscreen, for instance, they might put html javascript tags and run bad things for some users. In the case of html, you could use htmlentities or htmlspecialchars to "escape" html so that it cannot cause damage. Similar concerns will be taken for using in in SQL, for instance. For more info, look up cross site scripting and sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several ways. Here are two:

```
foreach($software1 as $key => $value){
    echo "$value {$software2[$key]}<br>";
}
```

Or if one or the other are guaranteed to be unique, use it as the key:

```
foreach(array_combine($software1, $software2) as $key => $value){
     echo "$key $value<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) here and concatenate both corresponding values from both arrays together creating a new array, e.g.

```
$result = array_map(function(...$v){
    return implode(" ", $v);
}, $software1, $software3 /* , more arrays */);
```

Of course if you just want to output it you can use `echo` inside `array_map()`. And if you have an unknown amount of arrays you want to merge by concatenation you can do it with `call_user_func_array()`, e.g.

```
$result = call_user_func_array("array_map", [function(...$v){return implode(" ", $v);}, $arrays]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do it: if `$software2` are unique value, you can use `array_combine`:

```
foreach (array_combine($_POST['software2'], $_POST['software1']) as $key => $val) {
    echo $val , ' ', $key; 
}
```